# Move tab left and right scrolling tab material design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i using metrical design tab. how to insert scroll in end right and left arrow move menu in hidden left or right
when there are too many tabs so when i click arrow icon if tab hidden scroll little view position ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Intial Border Position
  var activePos = $('.tabs-header .active').position();

  // Change Position
  function changePos() {

    // Update Position
    activePos = $('.tabs-header .active').position();

    // Change Position & Width
    $('.border').stop().css({
      left: activePos.left,
      width: $('.tabs-header .active').width()
    });
  }

  changePos();

  // Intial Tab Height
  var tabHeight = $('.tab.active').height();

  // Animate Tab Height
  function animateTabHeight() {

    // Update Tab Height
    tabHeight = $('.tab.active').height();

    // Animate Height
    $('.tabs-content').stop().css({
      height: tabHeight + 'px'
    });
  }

  animateTabHeight();

  // Change Tab
  function changeTab() {
    var getTabId = $('.tabs-header .active a').attr('tab-id');

    // Remove Active State
    $('.tab').stop().fadeOut(300, function() {
      // Remove Class
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }).hide();

    $('.tab[tab-id=' + getTabId + ']').stop().fadeIn(300, function() {
      // Add Class
      $(this).addClass('active');

      // Animate Height
      animateTabHeight();
    });
  }

  // Tabs
  $('.tabs-header a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Tab Id
    var tabId = $(this).attr('tab-id');

    // Remove Active State
    $('.tabs-header a').stop().parent().removeClass('active');

    // Add Active State
    $(this).stop().parent().addClass('active');

    changePos();

    // Update Current Itm
    tabCurrentItem = tabItems.filter('.active');

    // Remove Active State
    $('.tab').stop().fadeOut(300, function() {
      // Remove Class
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }).hide();

    // Add Active State
    $('.tab[tab-id="' + tabId + '"]').stop().fadeIn(300, function() {
      // Add Class
      $(this).addClass('active');

      // Animate Height
      animateTabHeight();
    });
  });

  // Tab Items
  var tabItems = $('.tabs-header ul li');

  // Tab Current Item
  var tabCurrentItem = tabItems.filter('.active');

  // Next Button
  $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nextItem = tabCurrentItem.next();

    tabCurrentItem.removeClass('active');

    if (nextItem.length) {
      tabCurrentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
    } else {
      tabCurrentItem = tabItems.first().addClass('active');
    }

    changePos();
    changeTab();
  });

  // Prev Button
  $('#prev').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var prevItem = tabCurrentItem.prev();

    tabCurrentItem.removeClass('active');

    if (prevItem.length) {
      tabCurrentItem = prevItem.addClass('active');
    } else {
      tabCurrentItem = tabItems.last().addClass('active');
    }

    changePos();
    changeTab();
  });

  // Ripple
  $('[ripple]').on('click', function(e) {
    var rippleDiv = $('<div class="ripple" />'),
      rippleOffset = $(this).offset(),
      rippleY = e.pageY - rippleOffset.top,
      rippleX = e.pageX - rippleOffset.left,
      ripple = $('.ripple');

    rippleDiv.css({
      top: rippleY - (ripple.height() / 2),
      left: rippleX - (ripple.width() / 2),
      background: $(this).attr("ripple-color")
    }).appendTo($(this));

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      rippleDiv.remove();
    }, 1500);
  });
});
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

```css
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block
}
body {
  line-height: 1
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(66, 183, 245, 0.8) 0%, rgba(66, 245, 189, 0.4) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(66, 183, 245, 0.8) 0%, rgba(66, 245, 189, 0.4) 100%);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
[ripple] {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[ripple] .ripple {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 1.6s;
  animation: ripple 1.6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(40);
    transform: scale(40);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(40);
    transform: scale(40);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.tabs {
  z-index: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 150px auto 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs-header {
  position: relative;
  background: #4285F4;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs-header .border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #F4B142;
  width: auto;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.tabs-header ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: calc(100% - 68px);
}
.tabs-header li {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.tabs-header a {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tabs-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #4285F4;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.tabs-nav:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #4285F4;
}
.tabs-nav i {
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs-content:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #FFFFFF;
}
.tabs-content .tab {
  display: none;
}
.tabs-content .tab.active {
  display: block;
}
.tabs-header ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: calc(100% - 68px);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Material Design Inspired Tabs Modal Demo</title>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">


<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs-header">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" tab-id="1" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-2" tab-id="2" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-3" tab-id="3" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-4" tab-id="4" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-5" tab-id="5" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-6" tab-id="6" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-7" tab-id="7" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-8" tab-id="8" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-9" tab-id="9" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF">Tab 9</a></li>
    </ul>
    <nav class="tabs-nav"><i id="prev" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF" class="material-icons">&#xE314;</i><i id="next" ripple="ripple" ripple-color="#FFF" class="material-icons">&#xE315;</i></nav>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-content">
    <div tab-id="1" class="tab active">1. Loremlentesque.</div>
    <div tab-id="2" class="tab">2. Donec vel nibh tortor. </div>
    <div tab-id="3" class="tab">3. Quisque suscipit ipsum </div>
    <div tab-id="4" class="tab">4. Maecenas felis risus, </div>
    <div tab-id="5" class="tab">5. Pellentesque ferme</div>
 <div tab-id="6" class="tab">6. Quisque suscipit </div>
    <div tab-id="7" class="tab">7. Maecenas felis </div>
 <div tab-id="8" class="tab">8. Quisque susc</div>
    <div tab-id="9" class="tab">9. Maecenas</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```